# Sequelize: SQL injection in findOne?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js

I have to use sequelize (with postgres) for a project.

I was wondering if it was possible to use [Replacement and bind parameters](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html) on functions (findOne (); findAll () ...), for prevent SQL injection ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Add your own efforts such as coding approaches and docs research.

Answer (score 0):

They do that work for us. When you use findOne, finally you are using prepared statements. A major benefit for using ORMs is that they make use of prepared statements, which is a technique to escape input in order to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities.